# Using jquery to get click coordinates relative to picture

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, facebook

I am trying to make a Facebook like photo tagging system, but with what I have so far, I can click on an image and I can get the coordinates, but when I try to make an input box appear at those coordinates it is offset because the div the img is located in isn't in the top right corner on the page. I could manually change the values of the x and y to get it more accurate but if I ever decide to restyle the page or move the div all of the coords of the tags in the database will be way off.  How does Facebook do it?  Is there a way to keep the coords relative to the containing div?

Here's What I have.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#photo").click(function(e) {
      var offset = $(this).offset();
      var x = (e.pageX + offset.left);
      var y = (e.pageY + offset.top);
      $("#tagger").css('top', y - 110); //manual offset
      $("#tagger").css('left', x-20); //manual offset
      $("#tagger").show().focus();
    });

  });
</script>
```

The div below needs to be ready to be placed anywhere on the page and still have a tagging functionality.

```
<div>
  <img id="photo" src="image.jpg" height="300" width="300">
  <input type="text" name="tagger" id="tagger">
</div>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: There is a really simple plugin i use for this http://www.bryantan.info/demo/phototag

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`.position`](http://api.jquery.com/position/) instead of [`.offset`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/). This will return the coordinates of the element relative to its parent container.

Comment: seems to have same issue. Thanks for the suggestion though.